# Unit test setup for accessing value from inner controller of a directive

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I'm testing an isolate directive that as an inner controller and directive scope value used in the controller.

This is the simplfied plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/r91xk1?p=preview from the real code which is directive wrapper for a grid but this is showing the issue.

excepts from test that is failing:

```
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $compile) {
      $compile = $compile;
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();

      //Here is the scope information defined, what we want to get into the directive
      $scope.itemToTest = "-beforeTest filled in valueFromTest--"

      // Here we declare that the "itemToTest" attribute is bound to the *value* of itemToTest
      elm = angular.element('<primary-grid itemToTest="itemToTest" ></primary-grid>');
      e = $compile(elm)($scope);
      $scope.$digest();
      console.log("in beforeEach $scope %o ", $scope.$id);
  }));


  it('should have filled in the value the grid', function() {
      // Access the isolateScope using <ELEMENT>.isolateScope, to see what's happening inside
      //This fails
      console.log("in Test e.scope() %o ", e.scope());
      console.log("in Test e.isolateScope() %o ", e.isolateScope().$id);
      console.log("in Test e.isolateScope().itemToTest %o ", e.isolateScope().itemToTest);
      console.log("in Test e  %o ", e);
      //This Test fails
      expect(e.isolateScope().itemToTest).toEqual($scope.itemToTest);
  })
```

...

Any ideas on what is the best way to set the correct value on the directive in the tests, so that the controller can use it and the code can the unit tested?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: Need to use 'item-to-test' as the attribute in the markup, not the camelCase (i.e. JS) name

use :

```
elm = angular.element('<primary-grid item-to-test="itemToTest" ></primary-grid>’);
```

instead of :

```
elm = angular.element('<primary-grid itemToTest="itemToTest" ></primary-grid>’);
```